# How to access OneDrive in Windows 8.1 without creating a Windows user

Tags: onedrive

At home I've been using OneDrive in Windows 7 until now. I used my Gmail email address to log in and it worked okay.

At my workplace, I use Windows 8.1. When I try to use OneDrive it asks for a USER (represented by a Microsoft account) on that computer and not an 'external' email address.

I do *NOT* want to create a user on my work computer with *my private email address* but I want to sync my OneDrive file with the account of my personal OneDrive, so I want to log in using my Gmail address.

Can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your workplace is most likely using OneDrive for Business, in which case the "external" email address it's asking you for will most likely be your Office 365 credentials. This will most likely be your work email and a password that you should know. (If not your IT can reset it for you).

OneDrive for business is just that, for business and will not allow you to sync different documents (e.g your Gmail). Your work OneDrive instance will be configured to work with your companies SharePoint 2013 server. - This is either a standalone SharePoint instance or will be linked to your companies Office 365.

As far as I know it is not possible to install personal and business versions side by side as they conflict heavily.

You will need to access either your personal or work documents via the portal whilst the other is synced via OneDrive.

Comment: I can see my OneDrive for Business, but it is not configured yet. I also have OneDrive metro app that asks for the Windows login. So basically I can't use my personal OneDrive without creating a Windows user?

Comment: You can't use your 'personal' without removing OneDrive for business and installing the standard 'personal' version.

Comment: Okay, I get it. Too bad, the original version was very easy to use. This centralized concept is too strict for me :(

Comment: Why are you trying to link your personal OneDrive account on your work computer?  You can access your OneDrive account through a browser though.

Comment: @Ramhound Because it is easy to update a file that is synchronized to my home computer and I can see the same file at home. It is more convenient than logging in the browser and manually access the files.

Comment: @Nestor - There are third-party OneDrive clients you can use instead.  You can also add your OneDrive as a network share.  You might want to make sure syncing your personal OneDrive account on their computer is something your company wants you to do

Answer (score 2):

I think the easiest way to upload a file to OneDrive from your work computer would be to login to OneDrive through a web browser.

As my organization also uses Windows 8.1 with a corporate OneDrive account; I have to use the web browser interface whenever I transfer files to my personal OneDrive while at work. The only issue is that I have to logout of the corporate OneDrive first before logging into my personal OneDrive.

I am sure there are other OneDrive clients out there that will work too, but I've always been a little hesitant of relying on something that may or may not be supported in the next release of OneDrive.